# file not dowloading in express and react

Tags: node.js, ajax, reactjs, express

i want to download file from folder to browser . my first code works fine .the file gets downloaded immediately but when i try to find the file specificly by id it does not works . dont know why ?

///client works

```
      $.ajax({
      type: 'GET' ,
      url: '/download' ,



      success : function()

      {
        window.open('/download?foo=bar&xxx=yyy');

      }


    });
```

/////server works

```
    app.get('/download', function(req, res) {



      res.download(__dirname + '/uploads/google.png');
    });
```

////client not works

```
          $.ajax({
          type: 'GET' ,
          url: '/download/' + id ,



          success : function()

          {
            window.open('/download?foo=bar&xxx=yyy');

          }


        });
```

/////server not working

```
      app.get('/download/:id', function(req, res) {

      var id  = req.params.id

      console.log("ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd")

      console.log(id)

      res.download(__dirname + '/uploads/google' + id  +'.png');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are passing values as query parameters and not URL parameter from client.

## Server side

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res) {

  var foo  = req.query.foo;
  var xxx = req.query.xxx;

  console.log(foo)
  console.log(xxx)

  //res.download(__dirname + '/uploads/google' + id  +'.png');
});
```

Comment: how can i download the file ? req.query.id  - this way ?